# AWS PHP SDK Version 2 S3 putObject Error

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

So the AWS php sdk 2.x library has been put out recently and I've taken a turkey day plunge into upgrading from 1.5x.  My first was to upgrade my S3 backup class.  I've quickly run into an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'EntityBody' not found in /usr/share/php/....my file here
```

when trying to upload a zipped file to an S3 bucket. I wrote a class to abstract the writing a bit to allow for multi-region backup, so the code below references to $this are that.

```
$response1 = $s3->create_object(
        $this->bucket_standard,
        $this->filename,
        array(
         'fileUpload'  => $this->filename,
         'encryption' => 'AES256',
         //'acl'         => AmazonS3::ACL_PRIVATE,
         'contentType' => 'text/plain',
         'storage'     => AmazonS3::STORAGE_REDUCED,
         'headers'     => array( // raw headers
                              'Cache-Control'    => 'max-age',
                              //'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip',
                              'Content-Language' => 'en-US'
                              //'Expires'       => 'Thu, 01 Nov 2012 16:00:00 GMT'
                            ),
          'meta'     => array(
                              'param1' => $this->backupDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),     // put some info on the file in meta tags
                              'param2' => $this->hostOrigin
                            ) 
            )
      );
```

The above worked fine on 1.5.x.

Now, in 2.x, I'm looking into their docs and they've changed just about everything (great...maximum sarcasm)

```
$s3opts=array('key'=> $this->accessKey, 'secret' => $this->secretKey,'region' => 'us-east-1');
$s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory($s3opts);
```

so now I've got a new S3 object. And here is my 2.x syntax to do the same exact thing.  My problem arises where they've (sinisterly) changed the old "fileupload" to "Body" and made it more abstract in how to actually attach a file!  I've tried both and I'm thinking it has to do with the dependencies (Guzzle or Smyfony etc), but I get the error above (or substitute Stream if you like) whenever I try to execute this.

I've tried using Composer with composer.json, and the aws.phar but before I get into that, is there something dumb I'm missing?

```
$response1 = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $this->bucket_standard,
        'Key'    => $this->filename,
        'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
        'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
        'Body' => EntityBody::factory(fopen($this->filename, 'r')),
        //'Body' => new Stream(fopen($fullPath, 'r')),

        'MetaData' => array(
                              'BackupTime' => $this->backupDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),     // put some info on the file in meta tags
                              'HostOrigin' => $this->hostOrigin
                            ) 
      ));
```

Thanks as always,

R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you import the EntityBody into your namespace?

```
use Guzzle\Http\EntityBody;
```

Otherwise, you'd have to do

```
'Body' => \Guzzle\Http\EntityBody::factory(fopen($this->filename, 'r')),
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - namespaces still not popping on my debug radar immediately yet.

Comment: No prob. If you are just getting into using namespaces, it takes a little getting used to. It'll be second nature soon.