# Uploading an Image using AWS SDK for PHP 2

Tags: php, image, upload, amazon-web-services

This is driving me crazy -- I have been working on this problem for several days with little success.  I've finally hit a brick wall and need help.  A lot of the articles and forums that I have searched are not for AWSSDK for PHP 2.

We have been using Amazon's S3 to load images through iOS for the past couple of years.

Now, I need to implement the upload in a browser.

I have downloaded and successfully installed AWSSDK for PHP 2 on our Ubuntu server.  I can get connected to our AWS S3 account and display the contents of the buckets.  But I am unable to put an image in a bucket.

The Exception from AWS is:
    Aws\S3\Exception\NotImplementedException: AWS Error Code: NotImplemented, Status Code: 501, AWS Request ID: CEDC4BBAA83CF70C, AWS Error Type: server, AWS Error Message: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented.

Here is the URL that I got the below example code from, under the heading called Uploading a File to Amazon S3:  https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php#quick-start

And I updated my code based on this:  [AWS PHP SDK Version 2 S3 putObject Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504065/aws-php-sdk-version-2-s3-putobject-error)

But it still doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once("../config.php");     //local config vars   
require_once('AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar');

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;
use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\S3\Enum\CannedAcl;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
use Guzzle\Http\EntityBody;

//get the $s3 object
$config = array(
    'key' => AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY,
    'secret' => AMAZON_ACCESS_SECRET,
    'region' => Region::US_EAST_1    
);
$s3 = S3Client::factory($config);


try {
    $bucketname = 'my_bucket_name';            //my bucket name on s3
    $filename = 'filename.jpg';                //my image on my server
    $path = 'http://my.website.com/app/cache/remote';        //the path where the image is located
    $fullfilename = $path."/".$filename;

    //this successfully lists the contents of the bucket I am interested in
    foreach ($s3->getIterator('ListBuckets') as $bucket) {
        foreach ($s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => $bucket['Name'])) as $object) {
            if ( $bucket['Name'] == $bucketname ) {
                echo $bucket['Name'] . '/' . $object['Key'] . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }

    //HERE ME HERE, PLEASE!  this is the code that throws the exception
    $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucketname,
        'Key'    => $filename, 
        'Body'   => EntityBody::factory(fopen($fullfilename, 'r')),
        'ACL'    => CannedAcl::PUBLIC_READ_WRITE,
        'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
    ));


} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}

?>
```

Can someone please provide me with an example so I can upload the JPG image into our bucket on S3 using AWSSDK for PHP 2?

RESOLUTION:
From ppostma1's reply, I have modified my code as follows, and it now works:

```
$bucketname = 'my_bucket_name';  //must be all lowercase
$filename = 'filename.jpg'; //my image on my server
$path = 'var/www/html/root-website-folder/images/'; //the physical path where the image is located
$fullfilename = $path.$filename;

$s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucketname,
        'Key'    => $filename, 
        'Body'   => EntityBody::factory(fopen($fullfilename, 'r')),
        'ACL'    => CannedAcl::PUBLIC_READ_WRITE,
        'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
));
```

Comment: are you using a proxy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are missing a s3 'filename' aka key:

```
'Key' => '/files/imgage/fuzzykitten.jpg'
```

Next, I have had far fewer complications with:

```
//use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;
//use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\S3\Enum\CannedAcl;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
use Guzzle\Http\EntityBody;


$amazon = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory($config)
```

with being able to find the class files. Every time I try to include ./common/aws or ./s3/s3client, it start giving me "cannot find Aws\S3\Aws\S3Client" which leaves me at wt???

Comment: Thanks, ppostma1.  Your answer pointed me in the right direction.  I do have the Key in the example above, but I was making 2 mistakes with my test.  1)  the Bucket Name MUST be lowercase letters.  My prod bucket is my dev bucket was upper and lower (why do they let you create a bucket name you can't use?).  2)  I was using the URL to access the filename, but from your post, I realized that I needed to use the full physical path on the server to the file.

Comment: ah!, when I didn't see a path I presumed there wasn't a Key.
Now for anyone hitting this up looking for a proxy, the additional code is:

    $configs = array(
      'key' => AWS_KEY,
      'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
      'curl.options' => array(
        CURLOPT_PROXY => 'proxyHostName',
        CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => PORT#,
        CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => 'username:Password',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Expect:"),
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> FALSE
      ) 
    );
    $amazon = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory($configs);

Comment: CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Expect:"), is needed only for "Squid" servers, and if you have those you might need the MS-domain username which would then be "domainhost\username:Password"