# Error upload to S3 bucket, something with EndPoint

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I try the following code [Uploading an Image using AWS SDK for PHP 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969921/uploading-an-image-using-aws-sdk-for-php-2), and it works for US Default Region (us-east-1), But when I create another bucket with Singapore Region ( I put ap-souteast-2 in the code) It returns error:

> The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the
>   specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint:
>   "mytestbucket.local.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com".

How to solve this problem?

Here's my code

```
$awsConfig = array(
                'key' => $this->container->getParameter('aws_key'),
                'secret' => $this->container->getParameter('aws_secret_key'),
                'region' => $this->container->getParameter('s3_region'),
            );
            $s3 = S3Client::factory($awsConfig);
            $bucketLists = array();
            try {
                $bucketname   = $this->container->getParameter('aws_bucket_name');
                $bucketFolder = $this->container->getParameter('upload_folder');
                $filename     = $user->getProfilePic();
                $fullfilename = $user->getAbsolutePath();

                $s3->putObject(array(
                    'Bucket' => $bucketname,
                    'Key'    => $bucketFolder.'/'.$filename, 
                    'Body'   => EntityBody::factory(fopen($fullfilename, 'r')),
                    'ACL'    => CannedAcl::PUBLIC_READ,
                    'ContentType' => mime_content_type($fullfilename)
                ));
                if (file_exists($fullfilename)) {
                    unlink($fullfilename);
                }
            } catch (S3Exception $e) {
                return $this->handleView( $this->view(array(
                'StatusCode' => 400, 
                'ErrorDesc' => $e->getMessage()), 400));
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `ap-southeast-1` region and not `ap-souteast-2` in the `$awsConfig` settings.

Comment: I don't realize that. Thanks for your help.